# Positioning Alert Box

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a Custom Alert box which gets displayed on a clicking of a row in a table. When I have multiple rows, I scroll down and click a row. The alert box gets displayed only at the top.

```js
var d = document;
  var c_obj = d.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(d.createElement("div"));
  c_obj.id = "contain";
  c_obj.style.height = d.documentElement.scrollHeight + "px";
  var alertObj = c_obj.appendChild(d.createElement("div"));
   alertObj.id = "alert";
   if (d.all && !window.opera)
   alertObj.style.top = document.documentElement.scrollTop + "px";
   alertObj.style.left = (d.documentElement.scrollWidth - alertObj.offsetWidth) / 2 + "px";
   alertObj.style.visiblity = "visible";
  var h3 = alertObj.appendChild(d.createElement("h3"));
   h3.appendChild(d.createTextNode(name));
  var msg = alertObj.appendChild(d.createElement("p"));
   msg.innerHTML = "Links : " +Links+'<br>';
   var btn = alertObj.appendChild(d.createElement("a"));
   btn.id = "close";
   btn.appendChild(d.createTextNode('ok'));
   btn.focus();
   btn.onclick = function() {
   c_obj.parentNode.removeChild(c_obj);
   };
   alertObj.style.display = "block";
```

```css
#contain{position:absolute;top:0;}
#alert{background:#CCE6FF;padding:10px;width:600px;height:250px;margin:300px;border-radius:15px;border:1px solid #a1a1a1;overflow-y: auto;}
#close{padding:5px; background:blue;color:white;border-radius:5px;cursor: pointer;}
```

What can I do to display the alert box in the center of the page no matter which row I click using CSS and JS

Answer (score 1):

In css you can do this with the `#alert` class:

```
#alert{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  margin:0;
  width:600px;
  height:250px;
  border:1px solid #a1a1a1;
  margin:auto;
  overflow-y:auto;
}
```

Adding `position:absolute`, giving `top`, `left`, `right` and `bottom` a value of `0` and giving margin `0` with a `width` and `height` means that it will be in the center of the screen.

Also remove `contain`'s `position:absolute` and `top:0;`.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qxovs3v4/)

```js
var d = document;
  var c_obj = d.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(d.createElement("div"));
  c_obj.id = "contain";
  c_obj.style.height = d.documentElement.scrollHeight + "px";
  var alertObj = c_obj.appendChild(d.createElement("div"));
   alertObj.id = "alert";
   if (d.all && !window.opera)
   alertObj.style.top = document.documentElement.scrollTop + "px";
   alertObj.style.left = (d.documentElement.scrollWidth - alertObj.offsetWidth) / 2 + "px";
   alertObj.style.visiblity = "visible";
  var h3 = alertObj.appendChild(d.createElement("h3"));
   h3.appendChild(d.createTextNode(name));
  var msg = alertObj.appendChild(d.createElement("p"));
   msg.innerHTML = "Links : " +Links+'<br>';
   var btn = alertObj.appendChild(d.createElement("a"));
   btn.id = "close";
   btn.appendChild(d.createTextNode('ok'));
   btn.focus();
   btn.onclick = function() {
   c_obj.parentNode.removeChild(c_obj);
   };
   alertObj.style.display = "block";
```

```css
#alert{position:absolute;top:0;left:0;right:0;bottom:0;margin:0;width:600px;height:250px;background:#CCE6FF;border:1px solid #a1a1a1;margin:auto;overflow-y:auto;}
#close{padding:5px; background:blue;color:white;border-radius:5px;cursor: pointer;}
```

Answer (score 1):

A good strategy to center an element in window
https://css-tricks.com/centering-percentage-widthheight-elements/
styling excerpt:

```
div {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

  width: 40%;
  height: 50%;

  padding: 20px;  
  background: red;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0 0 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```